# Eloquent where between dates in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I`m having trouble with an Eloquent query.
The structure of my Model is:

Coupon (for get discounts for a booking):

- period_start (coupon is valid for some specific periods)
- period_end (this end date, for example: the coupon is valid when you make a booking between 2018-02-01 and 2018-03-03)
- booking_start (the period of when the booking is done)
- booking_end (you can book for example from 2018-01-15 till 2018-01-30 only for the coupon to be valid)

Code:

```
$coupon = Coupon::where('period_start', '<=', $request->get('from_date'))
        ->where('period_end', '<=', $request->get('to_date'))
        ->where('booking_start', '<=', now()->format('Y-m-d'))
        ->where('booking_end', '>=', now()->format('Y-m-d'))
        ->first();
```

In the order field people pick two dates from a datepicker, thats where the `request()`'s are for.

This should work, but I don't get any results...

Comment: You're trying to access something from the form? Try `$request->input('from_date');`

Comment: No, this works.

Comment: have you tried manually executing the query to see if you get any results?

Comment: what is booking_start and end  now()-format('Y-M-d'); no sens

Answer (score -1):

What about using dateBetween?

```
$start = Carbon::parse($request->start)->startOfDay();  //2016-09-29 00:00:00.000000
$end = Carbon::parse($request->end)->endOfDay(); //2016-09-29 23:59:59.000000
$clicks->dateBetween($start, $end);
```

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/daterange-with-wherebetween

Comment: Please do not copy others code without proper attribution. Furthermore you might help OP more if you tailer the code to his example (which will already alter the code) and explain what it does and why it works.

Answer (score -2):

You should re format the date that get from the datepicker before query part, like this.

```
$date=date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $request->to_date)));
```

Comment: Laravel comes with Carbon. Just let Carbon parse the incoming date via a format. No need for some nasty string replacement here.